# Android: How can I set the animation duration of a WindowIsFloating activity when its size change? (e.g. Dialogs)

Tags: android, animation, dialog, android-animation

#### Prelude

I am creating a Dialog-ish thing for my application.
It has a `FragmentContainerView` inside, so the entire height of the Dialog changes.

I have `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition` set in the Fragment where its `FragmentContainerView` performs the Fragment transaction.

#### Problem

While the inner contents animates as expected, the outer bounds of this whole view does not animate along with it.
(It becomes larger too fast)

[image: captured animation]

The bottom bound should animate as the same speed with the bottom logo, but currently the bottom bound goes faster than the logo does.

Furthermore, the bottom half actually seems *not* animating, while the top half seems so.

#### What I did

The code I used are shown below.

##### Activity

The outer-most activity simply has one FragmentContainerView at its center.

```kotlin
class LoginFormActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var _binding: ActivityLoginFormBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        _binding = ActivityLoginFormBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        setContentView(binding.root)

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.commit {
                setReorderingAllowed(true)
                this.add<LoginPopupFragment>(R.id.fragmentContainerView)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

##### LoginPopupFragment

The parent Fragment for the login dialog.

```kotlin
class LoginPopupFragment : Fragment(), ShouldTransactListener {
    private var _binding: FragmentLoginPopupBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        _binding = FragmentLoginPopupBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        // add first inner-Fragment when this dialog shows up.
        childFragmentManager.commit {
            setReorderingAllowed(true)
            add(binding.dialogInnerContainer.id, viewModel.currentPage.value.java, null)
        }
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    override fun<T: Fragment> onTransition(targetClass: KClass<out T>) {
        // set Transition animatioins for switching Fragments
        val transition: Transition = cardStackIn(duration = 700)
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(binding.root, transition)

        // switch inner Fragment
        childFragmentManager.commit {
            setReorderingAllowed(true)
            replace(binding.dialogInnerContainer.id, targetClass.java, null)
            addToBackStack(null)
        }
    }

    /*
     * The animation constructor
     */
    @SuppressLint("RtlHardcoded")
    private fun cardStackIn(duration: Long): TransitionSet {
        return TransitionSet().apply {
            this.ordering = TransitionSet.ORDERING_TOGETHER

            // Outer parts and the previous Fragment
            addTransition(TransitionSet().apply {
                this.ordering = TransitionSet.ORDERING_TOGETHER

                // previous Fragment should Fade away
                addTransition(Fade().apply {
                    this.mode = Visibility.MODE_OUT
                    this.duration = duration / 2
                })

                // Outer elements (bounds and logos) should slide
                addTransition(ChangeBounds().apply {
                    this.duration = 50
                })
            })

            // the new Fragment will have a CardStack effect
            addTransition(TransitionSet().apply {
                this.ordering = TransitionSet.ORDERING_TOGETHER
                this.startDelay = duration / 7 * 2

                addTransition(Slide().apply {
                    this.slideEdge = Gravity.RIGHT
                    this.mode = Visibility.MODE_IN
                    this.duration = duration
                })

                addTransition(Fade().apply {
                    this.mode = Visibility.MODE_IN
                    this.duration = duration * 2 / 3
                })
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Interface to pass where to transact

```kotlin
interface ShouldTransactListener {
    fun<T: Fragment> onTransition(targetClass: KClass<out T>)
}
```

##### XMLs

Will remove some attributes in favor of readability (Tags are preserved)

###### activity xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

###### fragment xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/topBox"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingVertical="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/backIcon"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView android:id="@+id/logo" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:text="@string/loginPage_title" />

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="16dp">

            <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                android:id="@+id/dialog_inner_container" />

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_blue" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

##### styles

```xml
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/Widget.Material3.Button.TonalButton</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/rounded_dialog</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackgroundBlurRadius">20dp</item>

    <!--    settings for WindowIsFloating    -->
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">50%</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">85%</item>
    <item name="android:windowElevation">8dp</item>"
    <item name="android:windowClipToOutline">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">?android:isLightTheme</item>    
</style>
```